# React Native + styled components -> React does not recognize the `enterKeyHint` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This question was asked incompletely within: 67481661

Error:
"Warning: React does not recognize the `enterKeyHint` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `enterkeyhint` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element."

```
 <MyTextInput
     label="Email Address"
     placeholder="Enter Email Addresss"
     placeholderTextColor={grSilver}
     spellCheck="false"
     autocompletetype="email"
     enterkeyhint={''}
     keyboardType="email-address"
     icon="mail"
     type="email"
     required="true"
    ></MyTextInput>

export const MyTextInput = styled.TextInput`
    background-color: ${secondary};
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 55px;
    padding-right: 55px;
    border-radius: 5px;
`;
```

package.json:

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.6",
"@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.1",
"expo": "~42.0.1",
"expo-constants": "^11.0.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
"formik": "^2.2.9",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-screens": "^3.5.0",
"react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
"styled-components": "^5.3.0"
```

After a short research, it has been suggested to downgrade react-native-web to 0.12.1 but that is not working well to. Any suggestion how to avoid the warning (error)?

Comment: Why don't you use 'returnKeyType: "next" '

Comment: What would that achieve? Did not think about it. After entering    returnKeyType ="next" - TextInput, no improvement to mention. Could you please explain what did you mean by that?